# Installation Java on Ubuntu 22.04 update-alternatives: warning:

Tags: java, update-alternatives

Yesterday I have erased Windows and install Ubuntu 22.04 on Acer 8 yers old. With success.
I need JDK Java 11 for development like Android Studio and others software.

Here is the steps I produced to install Java on my new Ubuntu after this [tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72mz0-98vg8):
Download: `jdk-11.0.16_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` from Oracle page.
Unzip: `tar -xvf jdk-11.0.16_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
Create folder: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/`
Move unziped folder: `sudo mv jdk-11.0.16/* /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/`
Set alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java/" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/java" 1010
```

with result

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/java because link group java is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/java/ with a link
```

**And I'm stuck here.**

The result of command:
`sudo update-alternatives --config java` is:

```
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java/): /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/java because link group java is broken
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/java/ with a link
```

The result of command `sudo update-alternatives --list java` is:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/java
```

And `java --version`

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.15+10-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, or
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72build2
sudo apt install openjdk-18-jre-headless  # version 18~36ea-1
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.3+7-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
```

I have visited and read and see different web page and YouTube, and I don't find understanding of problem neither solution.

Someone can explain me please the meaning of the warning and help with solution.
Very thanks !!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106736/how-fix-mistake-made-with-update-alternatives has a fix to the exact same warning

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind. I have tried in this moment the solution. It's not working. The system response is still the same.

Comment: You used the version from the link? without the " s?

Comment: It has work for javac but not for java.
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/javac" 1010
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in auto mode

Comment: openJDK 11 is in the Ubuntu repositories, will it work for what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, when I don't have yet install nothing on Ubuntu, the **broken link group** mentioned in warning of `update-alternatives`, was caused by absence of JAVA_HOME variable.
I have reinstall the Ubuntu OS, and install JDK 11 in this sequence:
Download: `jdk-11.0.16_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` from Oracle page.
Unzip: `tar -xvf jdk-11.0.16_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`
Create folder: `sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/`
Move unziped folder: `sudo mv jdk-11.0.16/* /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/`
Set java var in /etc/environment: `PATH="...:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin` &
`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16"`
Ask Ubuntu to accept new variable without restart whole system:
`source /etc/environment`
Set alternatives:
`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/java" 0`
`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/javac" 0`
`sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/java`
`sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.16/bin/javac`

With result for `java -version`:

```
java version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.16+11-LTS-199)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.16+11-LTS-199, mixed mode)
```